# (swig) Using c++ Shared Library (so) in PHP

Tags: php, c++, shared-libraries, swig

I am running an application under Ubuntu 14.04. And I want to use a c++ - Shared Library(.so) in my php-Code. I dont't have the source-Code of the library. All I have is the libMyLib.so -File and the header files of the .so

Here is my libMyLib.h

```
#ifndef MyLib_H
#define MyLib_H
#include "ITest.h"
#include <string>

class MyLib {    
public :   
    virtual int setParam(int ID, int value) = 0;
    virtual int getValue(int ID, int *value) = 0;

};
```

The ITest.h

```
#ifndef ITest_H
#define ITest_H
class ITest {
public :

    enum firstEnum {       
        INT = 1,
        STRING = 2

    };

    struct sValue {
        ....
    };
};
```

How can I use swig now without having the source code? Is there any another way to use this shared library in php without using swig?

thank you for your reply and i apprecite!

Comment: All you need is header files and then link the generated code against the .so you have